# How can I change on Windows a registry value remotely

Tags: windows, ssh

I want to run this command:
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultPassword /d newpasswd /t REG_SZ /f
after connecting through the command line to a Windows host.

Right now, I can connect through ssh to it as Administrator but running the command does not cause any changes to happen.

Anyone knows why? What options do I have?

Comment: Is the [remote registry service enabled?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754820.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure that the registry setting isn't being changed?  Is there any error message?  What ssh daemon are you running?

Answer (score 1):

This could possibly be because of a mismatch in the architectures of your daemon versus your system. I had the same problem where my SSHd was 32-bit and I was trying to change a registry entry on a 64-bit machine. Upgrading the SSHd to 64-bit did the trick for me.